# How can I use the github Search REST Api to get files of a particular extension that were created after specific date?

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to run a GITHUB scan using the rest api to get the files of a particular extension.
The endpoint that I am trying to use is `q=repo:hcp-core-data/canonicals+pushed:>2019-09-01+extension:avsc&per_page=100` . It should return the files in the repo that were pushed after 2019-09-01, but it does not. It returns `"total_count"`as 0, even though there are files in the repo that were pushed after that date.